# JavaScript: Are arrow functions first class functions?

Tags: javascript

Seeing as how arrow functions have no `this`, they lack a pretty fundamental ability compared to regular functions: They can't be used as constructors, because they have no context.

With this in mind, are arrow functions considered first class functions?

edit: If arrow functions are considered first class functions, what are the properties of arrow functions that allow you to still call it one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Seeing as how arrow functions have no this, they lack a pretty fundamental ability compared to regular functions: They can't be used as constructors, because they have no context.

That only has to do with the function's execution, not its type. A `this` value is an aspect of execution, not of the function object itself.

> With this in mind, are arrow functions considered first class objects?

Yes, they are data objects just like any other object, with the unique difference that they contain executable code that can be invoked. The abilities and limitations of the different kinds of functions with respect to their invocation doesn't have any bearing on whether or not they're first class objects.

```js
const fn = foo => foo + 42
const fn2 = fn

console.log(fn == fn2) // true

console.log(fn(42))
console.log(fn2(42))

fn.foo = "bar"
console.log(fn2.foo) // "bar"
```

---

> edit: If arrow functions are considered first class functions, what are the properties of arrow functions that allow you to still call it one?

Same as the properties of traditional functions. They're all objects that inherit from `Function.prototype`. Their primary difference is in their invocation, which again doesn't alter the question of whether they're first class objects/functions. They can *syntactically* be used in any place any other object can be used.

Comment: @Andrew: That's quite a different question, and must really be asked before comparing one function type to another. Basically, they're objects that can be syntactically used as data like any other object. The interpreter/compiler won't throw a syntax error if you try to make them the value of a variable, or function parameter or any other construct that expects a value. Just like an Array is a special kind of object value, so is a function.

Comment: Hmm.. What do you mean by "They can syntactically be used in any place any other object can be used."? Because from how I interpret this statement, this is not true, because they cannot be used as constructors... at least not be used properly. `this` in a arrow function is the window/global object (or the scope above it). Are you saying that the functionality change is irrelevant, even though it is undesirable/wrong when it comes to constructors?

Comment: @Andrew: That's not a syntax problem; it's a runtime problem (a TypeError). When I say "syntactically", I mean that the parser will not throw a SyntaxError, like it would if you tried to, for example, assign an `if` statement to a variable.

Comment: I see. After your explanation, paired with some outside resources, I understand now.